# How to export an environment variable for children processes inside a ksh script?

Tags: c, bash, variables, ksh, environment

I'm working on an old `C` software. There is one `ksh` script which executes a `C` program, which then creates some other processes and ends. These processes remain alive.

I'm trying to set an environment variable inside my `ksh` script, so that it could be accessible in the newly created processes that are still alive.

I have tried this way :

```
#!/bin/ksh

VARIABLE=value
export VARIABLE

my_c_program
```

But that doesn't work... I have tried to :

1. change my ksh script to bash
2. create a wrapper script that creates and exports the variable and then executes the original ksh script (which just executes the C program)
3. sourcing my ksh script (or my wrapper script when trying with 2.) instead of executing 
   it

But nothing from that worked.

The only thing that works for now is when I explicitly, by hand, execute the command :

```
export VARIABLE
```

In the current bash terminal.

Why? Isn't it possible to do the export inside a script instead of doing it manually?

Comment: how are your reading the environment variable from C program?

Comment: With getenv("VARIABLE")
It works as I said when exporting explicitely from the current bash, and doesn't work (returns NULL) in all other cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is ok actually...

The fact is that the process I thought was the child of the C program executed in my ksh script was the child of another process executed before. The C program was just sending a message via shared memory to tell the other program to execute its child.

So indeed the environment variable never went from my C program to the other's child. The only time when I had that variable set in the child is when I executed the other program (the one which is the real parent of the child) in a shell where the variable was exported.

Answer (score 0):

The code above looks correct and it should work. Another way to do it is:

```
VARIABLE=value my_c_program
```

which exports the variable just for the program. Afterwards, the variable will be set but other external processes don't get a copy.

So why doesn't your script work? It's hard to tell but here are some tips to debug the issue:

1. Use `#!/bin/ksh -x` to enable debug output. Save the output in a file and then `grep VARIABLE` to make see what happens with it.
2. Check for typos.
3. Another shell script is like an external process. So create a script

   ```
   #!/bin/ksh

   echo $VARIABLE
   ```

   and call it instead of `my_c_program` just to make sure passing the variable on works.
4. Maybe the C does something unexpected. Use a debugger to make sure it does what you expect.

Comment: Trying with the shell script inside my shell shows that export works. Even worse ! I have tried to execute the program inside my ksh scrpt with gdb -x to break in it before it ends and when breaking in it, the variable is set !

I have tried with 2 variables, both exported in my ksh script, and only one exported in current shell by hand. Both are set in the ksh script, both are set in the first C program, and only the one I set by hand is set in the child process...

It's probably that the C code does strange things, but it's a huge software, nearly a million lines, difficult to debug.

Comment: Thank you by the way for all these tips :)

Comment: Set a breakpoint in `getenv()` and `execve()` (the latter allows to override the env variables for child processes)